# Having trouble conceptually understanding this Linked List code

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I am having some trouble understanding why the function `delete()` below works for deleting a node in a linked list. I abridged the rest of the code to make this all easier to read.

So, I understand we have a node `first` with a bunch of nodes linked to `first`. I also understand that in the `delete()` function, we need to create a new node `n` to traverse the list. Here's my hang up:

If we create a new node `n`, and set `n = first`, we've created a new node, and the node constructor defines that `n` will have a new node `n.next` as well. So, haven't we created a whole new list, separate from  the list that begins with `first`? When the `delete()` function gets to the point where it sets `n.next = n.next.next`, isn't that deleting a node in a whole separate list of `n` nodes? How does this delete the node that is linked off of `first`? Conceptually, this is my hang up.

How are we actually deleting the node in the list that begins with `first`?

Edit: I think maybe I answered my own question but I was hoping someone could verify. Does this work because both the `first` and `n` nodes are actually just references back to the `New Node()` object created in the `Add()` function? When I learned programming it was with C++ so I'm used to seeing pointers, and this code didn't make much sense; but as I understand it Java doesn't explicitly have pointers... so am I correct about all of this?

```
public class LinkedList {
    static class Node {
        public Node() { }
        public double item;
        public Node next;
    }

    int N;
    Node first;

    public LinkedList () {
        first = null;
        N = 0;

    public void delete (int k) {
        if (k == 0) {
            first = first.next;
            N--;
        }

        else {
            Node n = first;
            for (int i = 0; i < k-1; i++) {
                n = n.next;
            }
            n.next = n.next.next;
            N--;
        }
    }

    public void add (double item) {
        Node newfirst = new Node ();
        newfirst.item = item;
        newfirst.next = first;
        first = newfirst;
        N++;
    }

    private static void testDelete () {
        MyLinked b = new MyLinked ();
        b.add (1);
        print ("singleton", b);
        b.delete (0);
        print ("deleted", b);
        for (double i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
            b.add (i);
        }
        print ("bigger list", b);
        b.delete (0);
        print ("deleted at beginning", b);
        b.delete (10);
        print ("deleted at end", b);
        b.delete (4);
        print ("deleted in middle", b);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {    
        testDelete();
    }

}
```

Comment: This question is far too broad - in fact, I count at least three different questions here.  I recommend running this either in your favourite debugger or on a piece of paper, and narrow your post down to a single question.

Comment: Java doesn't explicitly have pointers, because *everything* is a pointer (more correctly, everything except primitive types are references), so yes.  This works because they are references.

Comment: @JoeC I'm sorry if it seemed to broad. I was trying to understand how creating a new node "n" to traverse the list, and then deleting one of the "n" nodes had any effect the originally created list of nodes. But "n" isn't actually a new node, it's just a new reference back to the originally instantiated node, correct? I'm new to Eclipse so running it in the debugger was still confusing, but I think I get it now, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because each linked list node simply contains a reference to your object and a reference to the next node. In order to delete a node, you simply need to make the previous node point to the one after it.

ie. Initial list:

```
linkedList
  ↓
node0 -> node1 -> node2 -> node3
```

1) If you then were to remove `node1`, then it'd look like this

```
linkedList
  ↓
node0 ----------> node2 -> node3
         node1 ----↑
```

`node0` would no longer point to `node1`, so if you tried to iterate from `node0` you'd go to `node2` next. However, `node1` would still "point" to `node2` (until it's garbage collected of course).

2) If you instead removed `node0`, it look like this:

```
       linkedList
           ↓
node0 -> node1 -> node2 -> node3
```

You simply move the `first` field of the `LinkedList` to point to `node1` and so, if you were to do `linkedList.first` you'd be accessing `node1`. `node0` however will eventually get garbage collected because nothing references it (unless you do that somewhere else).

Keep in mind that these cases are true for a singly-linked LinkedList. If you had a doubly-linked LinkedList then, the detaching and reattaching becomes a bit more complicated.

--

I think you have a misunderstanding of what "delete" does. In Java, users don't manually manage memory, so you don't call `malloc` or `delete`, `destroy`, etc. You simply remove all references to the object and they will eventually get garbage collected by the JVM.

In the above code, we're simply talking about "deleting" a `Node` from a `LinkedList` in terms of data structures.

Comment: I understand that we're not explicitly deleting the node object, and that we're just linking the node before to the next one, which essentially loses the object to be deleted. My hangup was the fact that the node n used to traverse the list seemed to create a whole different list of nodes, and I didn't understand how "deleting" a node from that list affected the original list. But n is just a reference back to the original object so that's how it works, right? Thanks!

Comment: Yep, `n`'s just a reference to the nodes as you traverse down the list and since it's defined within a function, it only ever lives on the stack anyways.